Rewrite rule not working in NextJS Config
I have tried to use rewrite rule of NextJS in next.config.js file to redirect urls '/lite' to '?amp=1' but it is not working in all scenerious.
Here is my next.config.js code.
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:articles/:slug/:id/lite/',
        destination: '/:articles/:slug/:id/?amp=1',
      }
    ];
  },

}

module.exports = nextConfig

It is working in case of
https://localhost:3000/article/trending/us-man-witnesses-his-kidney-transplant-procedure-indian-origin-surgeon-viral-photos-9415947/
but not in case of
https://localhost:3000/article/trending/trending-globally/us-man-witnesses-his-kidney-transplant-procedure-indian-origin-surgeon-viral-photos-9415947/
Please help me on this.

It looks like we need to update the rewrite rule, current configuration expects a single segment for :slug, but when there are multiple segments (e.g., trending-globally), it does not match, so that's why you are getting this issue.

I suggest you to update the given code to:


async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:articles/:slug*/:id/lite/',
        destination: '/:articles/:slug*/:id/?amp=1',
      }
    ];
  },

}
module.exports = nextConfig



Now this configuration works for both single and multiple segments (e.g., trending-globally) so it should work for both.
